# Hitting Ctrl and then 'Enter' twice when improving a suggested edit seems to submit it twice - but the second revision is blank

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits, reviewing

I was reviewing a suggested edit which I chose to 'Improve and Edit'.

Whilst editing I tend to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and arrow keys to jump across words quickly. I went to insert a couple of newlines with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but because I was holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> this was interpreted as a 'Submit Edit'.

Normally I wouldn't consider this a problem, but would go find the question and continue the edit whilst the 5 minute edit window still existed. The problem is I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> *twice* in order to start a new paragraph, and it seems that (looking at the [revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/224702/revisions)) it submitted an *edit* twice.

However, the second edit is completely blank, as seen here:

[image: Question Revision History with extra 'revision']

You can see the original suggested edit is revision 2, my (unfinished) improvement is revision 3, and the blank one is revision 4. It's probably showing as blank because there were no changes from the previous revision. I would've thought that a blank or 'no changes' revision would be rejected on the server side?

Here is the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224702/xbox-360-flash-drive-proplem) in question.

Comment: [Repro'd on the meta SE sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions)

Comment: So this appears to be a network wide issue.  Bump it to Meta.SE?

Comment: @MBraedley - my understanding is that questions tagged with [bug] end up on the SE team radar no matter which meta they're posted to - I wouldn't want to duplicate the question if that is the case